# undefined local variable or method `hospital_booking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following and what it is supposed to do is generate a report on the 18th of every month which is what is supposed to do. Just noticed a small problem. I am getting the following error

`undefined local variable or method hospital_booking`

that also points to the following:

```
 app/models/hospital_booking.rb:30:in `send_overtime_mail'
  app/controllers/hospital_bookings_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

I am certain my setup is correct. If someone can give me a hand in where I have messed up thanks.

**HosptialBooking**

```
  def self.send_overtime_mail(user, bookings)
    OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(user, hospital_booking).deliver
   end
```

**Scheduler.rake**

```
desc 'Send hospital bookings overtime report'
task :overtime_report => :environment do
  if Date.today.day == 18
    bookings = HospitalBooking.where(:day => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)
    user = User.where(:roles => :administrator).first
    OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(user, hospital_bookings).deliver
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send_overtime_mail` takes the parameter into `bookings` variable, and then you're using `hospital_booking` inside the method.

```
def self.send_overtime_mail(user, bookings)
  OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(user, bookings).deliver
end
```

should work.

Comment: Job sorted that was it, won't allow me to accept until 5 mins cheers though